# Not firing validation for Cancel link with jQuery validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

We are using jQuery Unobtrusive validate and MVC4. Our forms have a cancel anchor that we wanted to use to client-side reset the form.

We are using onFocusOut validation.

If we are focussed on a field that is invalid and press the cancel link the action of losing focus on the input field fires validation.

I know that if it was a submit button we could use a cancel class but that would only cause the submit time validation to not fire. The onFocusOut validation still fires.

We have a solution which involves us trapping onMouseDown on the cancel link, setting a DoNotValidate flag and then turning that flag off after. It works but does seem like a Kludge.

Is it because we are using onFocusOut? How do other people handle cancel when using OnFocusOut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no clean solution to this other than disabling validation to be performed in the `onblur` event. You could disable it and perform client side validation only for the `onsubmit` event. Otherwise the workaround you've discovered seems viable.